# PHP, error when using $_GET['pFullName'];?

Tags: php, get

I'm getting a fatal error when I'm trying to echo a player's name.

I'm still pretty new to PHP, it may be a rookie mistake but I've tried everything.

Here's my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A1S | e-tracker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">
        <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="#" method="get">
            Name: <input type="text" placeholder="Player Full Name" name="pFullname"><br>
            Date of Birth: <input type="date" name="pDob"><br>
            Weight: <input type="number" name="pWeight" placeholder="Pounds" min="0"><br>
            Height: <input type="number" name="pHeight" placeholder="Centimeters" min="0"><br>
            <input type="submit">

            <?php
            $playerName = $_GET['pFullName'];
              echo $playerName;
             ?>
        </form>
        
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you need to submit the form and place your PHP code outer from the `form`.

Comment: "I'm getting a fatal error" - I can not see any error message in your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code:

```
$playerName = isset($_GET['pFullname']) ?$_GET['pFullname'] :"";
echo $playerName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (If you are using PHP7):

```
<?php
$playerName = $_GET['pFullname']??'';
echo $playerName;
```

---

`??` - [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

> The null coalescing operator (??) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset(). It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

So it is equivalent to

```
$playerName = isset($_GET['pFullname']) ? $_GET['pFullname'] : '';
```

---

**Note:**
You are using `pFullName` instead of `pFullname`. Latter is the control name